# core data - storing an array into core data one - tomany relationship table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

[image]

In my contact table I insert the information of a picked contact from iphone's address book.

I store contact's name and number (at 0th index) and add two more fields twilio number and bool check through this code.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

Contacts * newContact = [NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"
                         inManagedObjectContext:context];

newContact.name = name;
newContact.number = phone;
newContact.isEligible = isEligible;
newContact.twilionumber = tempTwilioNumber;
```

The scenario is to pick all other phone numbers (other than at 0th index) which are in the form of array and save them in the ContactDetail table which has the attribute phone number.
The case is one contact can have multiple other numbers.

How could I insert that array into contactDetail table against one entry in the contacts table??

Comment: Does it have to be an array? You could use another entity called Phonenumber and create an one-to-many relationship between Phonenumber and ContactDetail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following code did the trick;

```
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

  Contacts * newContact = [NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"
                         inManagedObjectContext:context];

newContact.name = name;
newContact.number = phone;
newContact.isEligible = isEligible;
newContact.twilionumber = tempTwilioNumber;


for (int i=1; i<otherContactNumbersArray.count; i++)
{
    ContactDetail * newContactDetail = [NSEntityDescription
                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ContactDetail"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];

    newContactDetail.phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
    newContactDetail.contactInfo = newContact;
}

NSError *myError;
[context save:&myError];
```

Thank you very much three dozen visitors who didn't even bother to up the rating of the question so that I could find a solution early.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ContactDetail relationship should be one-to-many, not one-to-one. You also need to add an "index" property to ContactDetail. This way when you fetch details for your contact instance (details will be in a form of NSSet) you can sort them by index

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have set the relationship as one to many. The problem is within setting the data not fetching the data. Is there any way that I could pick the values from array index by index and store it in the core data table?